# Query to show all blog posts while linking in categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

So I have a query that should get all posts from a table while linking the posts categories and the user that created the post. What I am getting though is just a single post returned, not all posts. Below is the schema:

```
Posts
=====
id

Categories
==========
id

Post categories
===============
postID
categoryID
```

And here is the SQL code I have so far, kinda deep but it gets all categories concatenated into a single field.

```
SELECT
    blgpostcategories.*,
    blgcategories.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(blgcategories.name) AS categories,
    blgposts.*,
    users.firstName,
    users.id AS usersId,
    users.lastName,
    users.email
FROM blgposts
RIGHT OUTER JOIN blgpostcategories
    ON blgposts.id = blgpostcategories.postID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN blgcategories
    ON blgpostcategories.categoryID = blgcategories.id
INNER JOIN users
    ON blgposts.userID = users.id
```

UPDATED Query from JNK - Still only returning a single row :-(

```
SELECT
  blgpostcategories.*,
  blgcategories.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(blgcategories.name) AS categories,
  blgposts.*
FROM blgposts

LEFT OUTER JOIN blgpostcategories
  ON blgposts.id = blgpostcategories.postID
LEFT OUTER JOIN blgcategories
  ON blgpostcategories.categoryID = blgcategories.id
```

Comment: Not sure, I thought this was the way to approach it. Should I try inner join? I am absolutely positive users is populated.

Comment: I added an answer.  You want a `LEFT JOIN` I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639172/complexish-joins-question/5640198#5640198) by Adam Robinson to a similar question

> Because you're using an aggregate in
>   your query (GROUP_CONCAT), your query
>   is being grouped. Since you have no
>   group by clause, your group is the
>   entire result set (hence seeing every
>   tag the author has used). Because
>   MySQL allows for using non-grouped
>   columns in grouped statements, you
>   aren't getting an error, but you
>   aren't getting the query that you
>   want.
>
> In order to retrieve the proper
>   results, you need to group your query
>   on thread.id.

In your case just adding `GROUP BY blgcategories.id` should do it

Comment: This did it! Main difference is I did GROUP BY blgposts.id

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see right off the bat:

**1 -** Do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` not a `RIGHT`.  `RIGHT` means "show me all the stuff in the right table, whether or not I have anything matching in the left table."  You want everything from `blogposts` so do a left.

**2 -** Your `INNER JOIN` may be an issue as well.  Are you sure `users` is populated fully?

**EDIT:**

The issue is you are using an aggregate function without a `GROUP BY`!  Take out the `GROUP_CONCAT()` and it should work fine.

Comment: See my above edited query. Still feel very n00bish to this query stuff :-(

Comment: @Nathan - if you do a `SELECT * FROM Blogposts` how many rows do you get?

Comment: @JNK 2 rows are returned...I am thinking it has something to do with the whole joining of my categories etc. hmm...

Comment: @nathan - see my edit.  You get funny results when you use aggregates without a `GROUP BY`.  Most databases won't let you do this but MySQL does...

Comment: @JNK How would I go about getting the multiple categories that each post can reside in then? I am using the GROUP_CONCAT() to get all categories in a single row without repeating my post data.

Comment: @Nathan Stanford II -- Add a `GROUP BY` clause See [this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639172/complexish-joins-question/5640198#comment-6430940)

Comment: @Nathan - add a `GROUP BY`, probably on your Primary Key for the `Blogposts` table.